$2x^2(2x + 1) = \sqrt{(x^4 + 1)[x^4 + 1 + 8x(2x + 1)]},$ $x > 0$
I was solving a calculus problem and got to this point. I've   been spinning my wheels for over an hour now and I think it would be best to move on to other problems. I'd really appreciate if someone could take a look and provide some guidance on how to get through this last part.
$2x^2(2x + 1) = \sqrt{(x^4 + 1)[x^4 + 1 + 8x(2x + 1)]}, \quad x > 0$
The two items of interest seem to be $(x^4 + 1)$ and $x(2x + 1),$ and it seems the next logical step is to square both sides and try to get to some $f(x) = 0$ with $f(x) \geq 0,$ or to get $g(a) = g(b),$ with $g(x)$ being a continuous monotone function, but I was unable to reach either end.

The equality doesn't hold when $x=1.;$  Perhaps you made a mistake before you got to this point?

@J.W.Tanner Hi, sorry if I misunderstood you, but the task is to solve for $x,$ so it's true that the equality doesn't hold for all $x >0.$

I also want to add that the equality is likely to be correct as the positive root as found my my calculator $(~ 1.6632)$ matches the answer, which is $\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{-2 + 4\sqrt{2}}}{2}.$

Why don't you include the original problem as well? Perhaps you've made a mistake earlier as JWTanner pointed out. Or maybe there is an easier way to solve it. Squaring will lead to a polynomial of 8th degree, not an easy task to find roots.

@Vasili Hi, the original problem is a system of two equations, the first equation allows you to get $y$ per $x$ to plug into the 2nd equation, which is shown. The $x^2$ on LHS and $x^2$ in $16x^2$ on the RHS are originally $2y + 2,$ which is equal to $x^2$ by the first equation. I don't want to sound like I'm overassuming, but this is a multiple choice problem from a university entrance exam in my country, and it's supposed to be solved relatively fast within 1-5 mins, so there should be a neat way to get $x$ without solving the 9th polynomial 8th degree.

I also want to add, in case of any doubt, that I did nothing other than plugging $2y + 2 = x^2$ into the present equation, and my calculator returns the correct answer when prompted to solve this equation, so there should be no error. The task is to get the exact form of $x,$ which is shown above.

For context, I've solved many of these problems before in preparation for this exam, and they almost always involve a neat way to obtain the answer from a complicated expression. E.g. evaluation using one or more layers of inequalities (AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz,  triangle inequality, etc.), monotone behavior, odd-even functions, common algebraic identities from high school etc. So any successful attempt to solve these problems within the time constraint is unlikely to be by brute force.

Squaring does lead to a nice form $(x^4-4x-1)^2=0$ but I do not see a simple way to solve this.

See this question

@Vasili Sorry for the late response! I just got back from school. Is there any way to quickly get to $(x^4 - 4x - 1)^2?$ Upon seeing your answer, I tried to look for hints for the square form but only managed to find it once I expanded the original expression.

@J.W.Tanner Thank you!

Actually, squaring both parts leads to
$$x^8-8x^5-2x^4+16x^2+8x+1=0 \\ 
(x^4-4x)^2-2(x^4-4x)+1=0 \\
(x^4-4x-1)^2=0 \\
x^4-4x-1=0
$$
The resulting equation is solved here (credit to @J.W.Tanner)

Thank you very much!

We can square both sides and get $$(2x^2(2x + 1))^2 = (x^4 + 1)[x^4 + 1 + 8x(2x + 1)]$$
then by simplifying successively like so
$$16x^6+16x^5+4x^4=x^8+16x^6+8x^5+2x^4+16x^2+8x+1$$
$$x^8-8x^5-2x^4+16x^2+8x+1=0 \\
(x^4-4x-1)^2=0 \\x^4-4x-1=0$$
This can be manipulated and factorized
$$(x^2+1)^2 - 2(x+1)^2 =0\\(x^2+1)^2-[\sqrt2(x+1)]^2=0\\(x^2+1- \sqrt{2}(x+1))(x^2+1+[\sqrt2(x+1))=0$$
Now we just have to solve the two quadratics to get that
$$x_1=\frac{ \sqrt{2}- \sqrt{-2+4\sqrt{2}}}{2} , x_2=\frac{ \sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{-2+4\sqrt{2}}}{2}$$

Thank you very much!

Also since in your original equation we're talking about $x>0$ you only need to keep $x_2$
